Al leer código QR no muestra opciones de MsgBox sino que asume una opción del msgbox
Al leer un código QR que está impreso, el sistema no muestra la confirmación de lo que se desea hacer mediante la ejecución de un msgbox, sino que asume directamente el valor NO del msgbox. La lectura se hace con un lector de códigos
La validación del código QR la realizo en el TextChanged de un control Textbox, cuando se llega a la longitud máxima del control Textbox, la cual es de 6 caracteres.
El código que realizo en el textbox de captura del QR es:
    Private Sub txtBusquedaOrden_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtBusquedaOrden.TextChanged
    If Len(txtBusquedaOrden.Text) = txtBusquedaOrden.MaxLength Then
       Dim NumeroOrden As Long = Val(txtBusquedaOrden.Text)

       Try
           Dim style = MsgBoxStyle.YesNoCancel Or MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton2 Or MsgBoxStyle.Information

          Dim msg As String = "ORDEN No. " & NumeroOrden & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Seleccione : " & vbCrLf & "SI para CARGAR ORDEN" & vbCrLf & "NO para CERRAR ORDEN " & vbCrLf
           Dim title As String = "Orden"
           Dim response = MsgBox(msg, style, title)

           Select Case response
               Case Is = 6
                   CargaOrdendesdeQR(NumeroOrden)
                   txtBusquedaOrden.Text = ""
                   txtBusquedaOrden.Focus()
               Case Is = 7
                   CierraOrdendesdeQR(NumeroOrden)
                   txtBusquedaOrden.Text = ""
                   txtBusquedaOrden.Focus()
               Case Else
                   txtBusquedaOrden.Text = ""
                   txtBusquedaOrden.Focus()
           End Select
       Catch ex As Exception
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
       End Try
    End If
End Sub


Saludos. Con MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton2 le indicas que el botón seleccionado por default (y por consiguiente valor que te está retornando) sea el botón 2; que para tu vaso es No, si mal no recuerdo el MsgBoxStyle.YesNoCancel así es como aparecen en la ventana de diálogo que muestras.

Hola Roberto, gracias por tu respuesta. Correcto lo que mencionas, pero lo que yo quiero es que no se ejecute ninguna de las opciones del msgbox, sólo que el sistema espere que el usuario escoja la opción, pero al leer el QR se está ejecutando automáticamente la opción predeterminada, es decir que no espera a que se escoja la opción.

de que messagebox hablas, si no estas mostrando ninguno, salvo en el catch del error??? o acaso hay una funcion msgbox que muestra un messagebox, la cual no vemos y no sabemos que pasa??

Hola gbianchi, la variable response tiene asignada la respuesta del msgbox

Lo curioso es que si lleno el textbox manualmente con el código a validar, es decir sin leer el QR, allí si se ejecuta bien el programa y se me muestran las opciones del msgbox al completar la longitud del texto el valor máximo del textbox.

Saludos de nuevo @FernandoDiaz; En el keypress (o equivalente) monitorea la "pulsación" del ENTER éste se introduce en automático al final de cada lectura de código, vigila cada char "ingresado"; cuando usas un control donde puedes montirear el evento antes mencionado se soluciona. En tu caso prueba omitir el MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton2 y cualquiera similar.

Excelente Roberto, muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Efectivamente el inconveniente se presenta por el Enter que adiciona el lector al finalizar cada código. Se lo desactivé en la configuración del lector y ya funciona como deseo. No hubo necesidad de modificar el código de mi programa.

Se solucionó la situación desactivando en la configuración del lector de códigos el Enter automático que se adicionaba como sufijo y ya funciona como deseo. Gracias.
